# Moving a metabox - not obeying context or removing old

Tags: metabox

I have a custom taxonomy called "events category" that is in a custom post type called "events" - I want to move this metabox from the "side context to the "normal" context.

```
add_action('do_meta_boxes', 'move_event_categories_meta' );

function move_event_categories_meta() {
    remove_meta_box( 'events_locationsdiv', 'events', 'side' );
    add_meta_box('events_locationsdiv', __('XX Categories'), 'post_categories_meta_box', 'events', 'normal', 'high', array( 'taxonomy' => 'events_category' ));
}
```

There's two things that aren't happening with the above code.

1. The original metabox still shows
2. A new metabox is added, but still in the side context, not the normal context.

Can anyone see why this might be going wrong?

Comment: Meta box positions are saved per-user, so if you've visited a page with meta boxes on it then any future changes to their positions probably won't affect you. Try giving it a different ID.

Comment: Interesting - that seems to solve the problem. Is there a good way to flush this user data so ID changes aren't required? Also, the original metabox still isn't being removed.

Comment: Make sure `remove_meta_box()` still uses the old ID. In terms of flushing it there might be plugins that do it, but if you look in the database in the `usermeta` table each user will have a `metaboxhidden_post`, `metaboxhidden_page` etc. entry for each post type. This has the positions of the meta boxes for that post type for that user. If you delete it they should reset to their default positions.